# Extracting Data out of a input box inside a table cell using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have some table that looks like this:

```
<table width="650" id="myTable" runat="server">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" />&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" />&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" />&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I want to rip data out of that and store it in an XML file.  The problem is that the number of rows is unknown.  A user can create anywhere between 3 and n rows.  To solve this, I wrote a little loop that pulls data out of the table by row.

```
// Assume the relevant items are declared and assigned a proper value.

        while (i < myTable.Rows.Count)
        {
            tRow = myTable.Rows[i];

            tNameNode.InnerText = tRow.Cells[0].InnerText;
            tUnitsNode.InnerText = tRow.Cells[1].InnerText;
            tValueNode.InnerText = tRow.Cells[2].InnerText;

            tNewEntryNode.AppendChild(tNameNode);
            tNewEntryNode.AppendChild(tUnitsNode);
            tNewEntryNode.AppendChild(tValueNode);

            tIntermediateNode.AppendChild(tNewEntryNode);

            i++;
        }
```

Now the problem with this that I realized only after I ran it is that it's not going to fetch what is inside the input box, just the actual input box code, which is not really what I want.

How can I get the content inside the Input boxes?

Comment: You could develop some script to grab all of the text values of the generated textboxes by assigning them all the same ID and then have the script grab the values by ID.  Then store it to a variable that you can access in your C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I employed looked like this:

```
    while (i < myTable.Rows.Count)
    {
        tRow = tblCropsAndFeed.Rows[i];

        string tInputBox0 = tRow.Cells[0].Controls[0].ClientID;
        tContent = (HtmlInputText)tRow.FindControl(tInputBox0);
        tNameNode.InnerText = tContent.Value;

        string tInputBox1 = tRow.Cells[1].Controls[0].ClientID;
        tContent = (HtmlInputText)tRow.FindControl(tInputBox1);
        tUnitsNode.InnerText = tContent.Value;

        string tInputBox2 = tRow.Cells[2].Controls[0].ClientID;
        tContent = (HtmlInputText)tRow.FindControl(tInputBox2);
        tValueNode.InnerText = tContent.Value;

        tNewEntryNode.AppendChild(tNameNode);
        tNewEntryNode.AppendChild(tUnitsNode);
        tNewEntryNode.AppendChild(tValueNode);

        tCropsAndFeedNode.AppendChild(tNewEntryNode);

        i++;
    }
```

The huge problem I encountered was the C# was treating the input boxes as a DirectControl object, which made it pretty impossible to get anything out of it.  After adding

```
runat="server"
```

To the input boxes, all was fine however.

Answer (score 0):

You could develop some script to grab all of the text values of the generated textboxes by assigning them all the same ID and then have the script grab the values by ID. Then store it to a variable that you can access in your C# code

The HTML for your textboxes and including a hidden TextBox that could be filled with the value of the rest of your textboxes using a script:

```
<input type="text" class="userTxtBox" />
<input type="hidden" Id="hiddenTxtBox" />
```

Personal preference for JQuery at this point (but I'm pretty sure you could accomplish something similar with any script):

```
$('body').live('input','.userTxtBox', function () {
  $('#hiddenTxtBox').val($('.userTxtBox').val());
});
```

Then, in your C# code you can grab the text from the hiddenTxtBox.

Comment: The problem will be that Ids have to be unique.  I was thinking about doing something similar with class names though.

Comment: Right, that JQuery script is looking for inputs with a class of 'userTxtBox'.  However, that particular bit of script doesn't work, there's an error with the syntax.  I just tried it out in a jsfiddle.

Comment: I apologize, I can't get that script code correct right now in my fiddle.  But this is along the right track.  I'll be back later when I have more time but right now something else requires my attention.  But don't worry, this community is great! At least it has been so far for me, someone else will be along soon!

Comment: Many thanks for the attempt!  It's definitely gives me a place to start thinking about solutions!

Answer (score 0):

This is a very rough sketch of another way to do what you're doing, but probably is more maintainable in the long run than adding straight html. It looks like the rows you are adding all follow some common pattern and even represent some common functionality. .NET webforms has something expressly made for this purpose: usercontrols. Make a user control like

```
<% @ Control Language="C#" ClassName="InputRow" %>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><asp:textbox ... /></td>
    <td><asp:textbox ... /></td>
    <td><asp:textbox ... /></td>
    <td><asp:textbox ... /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Register it in your main page. Then, instead of adding input boxes, use

```
myTable.Controls.Add(new InputRow(...
```

My webforms is admittedly a little rusty, you may not actually be able to add directly to the Controls property of a table class. If that fails, you can always add it to the Controls property of an Asp:Panel object instead.

The reason this will be more maintainable is that you can then encapsulate the fetching logic of the input boxes in your usercontrol, and also use it on other pages. Keeping track of a set of these controls in a list will let you be able to object-oriented-ly iterate over all of them and pull out their data in a structured manner.